# I can't execute my stored procedure, my query just keep running

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im just trying using stored procedure in mysql. i tried to create a table name "Book". i have 5 columns before. they are idBook, bookName, bookYear, and Stock. So, i added 2 columns for rating and review. and i wanted to give those column with value using looping in stored procedure. and this is my code :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getBookExcitement`()
BEGIN

DECLARE bookRating INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE bookReview VARCHAR (100);

DECLARE sums INT;
SELECT count(idBook) INTO sums FROM Book;



getBookExcitement : LOOP

SET count = count+1;

    IF count<sums then

        SELECT FLOOR(1 + (rand()*5)) INTO bookRating;

            IF bookRating <3 then

                SET bookReview = 'This book isn't good';


            ELSEIF bookRating <=4 OR bookRating  >=3 then

                SET bookReview = 'This book is good';

            ELSE 

                SET bookReview = 'This book is very good, you should read it';

            END IF;

                UPDATE Book SET Rating = bookRating AND Review = bookReview 
                WHERE idBuku=count;
    END IF;


END LOOP getBookExcitement;

END
```

but when i try to call it, my workbench just keep executing the query non stop. Just like it stuck in loop. but the way i see it, i cant find something wrong with that looping, please help me since im new with stored procedure in mysql.

thanks

Comment: Please stop apologizing and simply ask your question.

Comment: @duffymo i was trying to be polite. But, i know what to do from now. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no `LEAVE getBookExcitement;`
Put an `else` at the end of the `IF count<sums then` block, with a LEAVE statement.